# How to select fourth decimal digit dynamically using binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to select the fourth decimal number dynamically in WPF. I know using `String.Format()` we can but how to select the fourth or fifth decimal place digit but I am not getting it. I have tried so many types but still not finding any solution. I also need the data to be fetched using data binding.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZIBP.png]

My final output is to be like as shown in this image. So I need to select last two digit number to make its font size larger and also using `BaselineAlignment="Superscript"`.

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/AGQqX.png]

This is my xaml code "**check at Binding Ask**" and **stringformat** just run the code to get the idea.

```
' <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button  Click="OnBuyClicked">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <TextBlock Background="{Binding Ask, Converter={StaticResource makeBrush}}" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" >

                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ask, StringFormat=0.###}"/>                                            
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Ask,StringFormat='{}{0:###01}'}" FontSize="28" />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Ask,StringFormat=#}" FontSize="8" BaselineAlignment="Superscript" />

                                    </TextBlock>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>'
```

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a custom binding, I don't believe you can do this with WPF's built-in databinding syntax.

Comment: Thank u for reply i don't no how to do using custom binding. can u please help me or give me some example to do. It would be more helpful.

Comment: hmm is their any exact solution for this ? how to do it?

Comment: I don't think anyone has had to do this (in WPF) before, so you'll need to research how to implement a custom one-way binding formatter and code the logic to get the 4th decimal place yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not clear at all. Where exactly is the number in the first place? It should be in a model data structure; given that, what's binding got to do with the question? Why not extract the digit straight from the model? How does selecting the fourth digit relate to the formatting issue you also describe? You will likely need to use a `RichTextBox` or similar to accomplish that latter, but without more details it's not possible to say specifically how.

Comment: Please improve your question by adding a good [mcve] that shows what you've got so far, along with a precise explanation of what it is you want that code to do that it's not doing now.

Comment: thank u peter Duniho for suggestion i will take it as advice and i have posted my Answer how it should look like.it would be glad if u could help me out to solve .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a converter to format the value or like @ProgrammingDude said, just create 3 more properties with those formatting.

The Converter solution:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converter:SmallRunConverter x:Key="SmallRunConverter"/>
        <converter:LargeRunConverter x:Key="LargeRunConverter"/>
        <converter:PowerRunConverter x:Key="PowerRunConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Ask, Converter={StaticResource SmallRunConverter}}"/>
                <Run FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Ask, Converter={StaticResource LargeRunConverter}}"/>
                <Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript" FontSize="8" Text="{Binding Ask, Converter={StaticResource PowerRunConverter}}" />
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

Sample Implementation of the LargeRunConverter (just for you to get the idea, modify the convert logic for your needs):

```
public class LargeRunConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double input = ((double) value) * 1000;
        double decimalPart = input - Math.Truncate(input);
        decimalPart = decimalPart * 100;
        return string.Format("{0:00}", decimalPart);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' <Grid>
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run FontSize="10" x:Name="SmallRun" >
                   .567
                </Run>
                <Run FontSize="20" x:Name="LargeRun">
                    34
                </Run>
                <Run x:Name="PowerRun" BaselineAlignment="Superscript" FontSize="8">
                    4
                </Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>'
```

This is the code and the output i needed. But now the values are static but i need to take the values from c# program how to code and Bind to xaml file Dynamically?

Comment: please can any one suggest me how to do it ? the value should be taken from c# program

Comment: for example 
0.567344,

value1= 0.567---> one value,
value2= 34----->most significant value,
value3= 4--->least significant value

Comment: Can't you bind the Text Property of the Run tags to a property in your code? You would have to create three different properties and set them equal to the values you needed from the main property you are wanting to bind to.